# Slide up a whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have created a site with a splash page at the beginning which I then want to slide up above the screen and disappear when the arrow is pressed. I am trying to do this using an animation in Jquery. I have created a [Fiddle](https://goo.gl/KOAZMM) for you to check the code.

HTML

```
        <div class='sc'>
        <div class='welcome'>
            <h1>Welcome to Brownsover Walkers</h1>
        </div>

        <div class='intro'>
            <p>#1 dog walkers in the Brownsover area</p>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var load = function(){
    $('.welcome').hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.intro').delay(1300).hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $('.arrow').delay(3000).hide().fadeIn(2000);
}

var unveil = function(){
    $('.arrow').click(function(){
        $('.sc').animate({
            bottom: '5000px'
        }, 500);
    });
}

$(document).ready(load,unveil);
```

CSS

```
html { 
  background: url(http://www.brwalkers.esy.es/images/bg3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.sc{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 6px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 6px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
    box-shadow: 2px 6px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
}

.sc h1{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px; 
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    top: 30%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.sc p{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 45%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.arrow{
    position: relative;
}

#arrow1{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 45%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few mistakes in your code.

1. You are passing multiple handlers into `.ready()`. You can only pass in one.
2. Call `.animate()` on `html` and `body` instead
3. In `.animate()` set scrollTop if you are wanting to go to the top of the page

[Here is the updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/camiblanch/7kfezfuu/1/)

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. I presume it's all got something to do with the full page div .sc not being able to move but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Then the issue is the code that's making it scroll up. I made the display window very small and was able to see the behavior. If you can see the whole page already because it is a short page, scrolling to the top won't really do anything. You have to adjust the page content to be longer to see the effect.